# Am I implementing MVP architecture correctly?

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

Currently I implemented the *MVP* architecture into one of my *Activities*. It works, but I need some clarification if I am doing it correctly.

In my *Activitiy*'s contract I have

```
public interface MainActivityContract {
    interface View{
        void updateEventName(String eventName);
        void updateEventDate(String eventDate);
        void updateEventTime(String eventTime);
    }

    interface Presenter{     
        void setEventName();
        void setEventDate();
        void setEventTime();      
    }
}
```

And in my `MainActivity` I would call the method

```
mPresenter.setEventInfo(mInfo);
```

from my `MainActivityPresenter` class:

```
private EventDto.EventInfo eventInfo;

@Override
    public void setEventInfo(EventDto.EventInfo eventInfo) {
        this.eventInfo = eventInfo;
        setEventName();
        setEventDate();
        setEventTime();     
    }

    @Override
    public void setEventName() {
        view.updateEventName(eventInfo.getE_name());
    }

    @Override
    public void setEventDate() {
        view.updateEventDate(eventInfo.getE_day());
    }

    @Override
    public void setEventTime() {
        view.updateEventTime(eventInfo.getE_time());
    }
```

**Is it correct to call all the update methods when calling one of the mPresenter methods?**

```
mPresenter.setEventInfo(mInfo);
```

Otherwise I would have to call the update methods one by one

```
mPresenter.setEventName()
mPresenter.setEventDate()
mPresenter.setEventTime()
```

Comment: It'd be easier to expose changes through the Observer pattern, rather than having to remember each callback you have to invoke manually by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `eventName`, `eventDate` and `eventTime` on *View*, *meaning interface here*, through either single or multiple method invocation(s) should rather depend on the way the data is retrieved by *Presenter* from *Model*, i.e. by a single or multiple calls respectively. But that is not my key point...

The way you utilize the MVP pattern is wrong.

In [**MVP**](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-mvp-architecture-101-cf6eaa0908f3):

1. *Presenter* gets data from *Model*
2. *Presenter* updates *View* with the data
3. *View* notifies *Presenter* on data changes (*if any*)

In **your approach**:

1. *View* gets data from *Model*
2. *View* updates *Presenter* with the data
3. *Presenter* updates *View* back with the data fields, `eventName`, `eventDate` and `eventTime`

Summing up, with your approach *View* also acts as *Model*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is right way , you can check https://medium.com/indianic/mvp-model-view-presenter-in-android-6487b9fafcbb also